# How to determine if a certain model is bound from request body or from route or from query parameters, etc. in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, action-filter, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using `ASP.NET Core 5.0` with `.NET 5.0` on Windows. One thing I need to do is from a `ActionFilter` to determine if a particular action argument is bound using request body. Is there a way to inspect the data source of the action method argument?

Comment: What you mean about bind from body or from route? As far as I know, if you just contain one model class, it will bind from body and querystring . So there is no way to know it bind from body or querystring. Could you please tell me why you need to know where it bind from?

Comment: @BrandoZhang the reason is that I want to log the json body of the request in the action filter if there is one and replay this request using a command line tool. This is a rare scenario. I could read the request body again. But in the action filter, the request body is already read.

Comment: After model binding there is no way to read the body again since the body is steam it could only be read once. Have you consider doing this things by using middleware? It happens before the model binder and it could read it.

Comment: @BrandoZhang ok, will consider that. Thanks!